# How to revoke token for an user

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

How I can do to revoke token for a user?

This is my authenticate code and I want to reset (revoke) access for one user. This is because I use the [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) and I want allow my user to change their email if necessary.

Actually the tokens are save with login at moment where token is reach but I must change this value when user decide to change their email.

```
Dim datafolder As String = Server.MapPath("App_Data/GoogleService.api.auth.store")
        Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim UserId As String = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString

        scopes.Add(DriveService.Scope.Drive)
        scopes.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom)
        Dim myclientsecret As New ClientSecrets() With { _
          .ClientId = CLIENT_ID, _
          .ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET _
        }

        Dim flow As GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

        flow = New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer() With { _
           .DataStore = New FileDataStore(datafolder), _
           .ClientSecrets = myclientsecret, _
           .Scopes = scopes _
         })

        Dim uri As String = Request.Url.ToString()

        Dim code = Request("code")

        If code IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code, uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result

            ' Extract the right state.
            Dim oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(flow.DataStore, UserId, Request("state")).Result
            Response.Redirect(oauthState)
        Else
            Dim result = New AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId, CancellationToken.None).Result
            If result.RedirectUri IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Redirect the user to the authorization server.
                Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri)
            Else
                ' The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
                myDriveService = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
                  .ApplicationName = "Liens Google SyGED", _
                  .HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential _
                })

                myGMailService = New GmailService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
               .ApplicationName = "Liens Google SyGED", _
               .HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential _
             })

            End If
        End If
```

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the file for userid?

Comment: I don't find file on my server

Comment: Filedatastore stores the file in %appdata% have you checked there?

Comment: I don't see any file in AppData

Comment: I found finally. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke token by making a call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}

Read https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer